# Python select multiple columns from a tab-separated text file

Tags: python, arrays, regex

I'm trying to extract multiple columns from a text file and ended up with the code below, which extracts all the columns from `17` to the last. I am trying to figure out a regex combination to tell the code what other exact columns to retrieve, but am kinda stuck.

Can someone please give me a hint?

```
f = open("datafile1.txt", "r")
g = open("datafile2.txt", "w")

for line in f:
  if line.strip():
    g.write("\t".join(line.split("\t")[17:]))

f.close()
g.close()
```

Comment: Why don't you read it with pandas? and keep only the columns you want

Comment: What columns do you want to read?

Comment: If it is a tab-separated file you can read it with  the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module from the standard library.  Using csv (or Pandas) is better than trying to use a regex which will break if any column has embedded tabs.

Comment: Alberto, i should for sure be using pandas, and am installing the module. But since i already started this task without it i figured to finish it that way.

Comment: Amir, would need to read columns 18, 26, 41 and 45.

Comment: Snakecharmeb, it is tab separated. Will try your suggestion.

Comment: Could you provide your input and your desired output?  It's hard to understand what you want especially without seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with a simple list comprehension, like this:

```
f = open("datafile1.txt", "r")
g = open("datafile2.txt", "w")

for line in f:
  if line.strip():
    g.write("\t".join([line.split("\t")[i] for i in [18, 26, 41, 45]]))

f.close()
g.close()
```